# multiply all the integers in a list of lists python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to multiply all the values in a list of lists in python:

```
    input = 3*[[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
```

so i get this output:

```
    output = [[3,6,9],[9,6,3]]
```

i tried this:

```
    l = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
    l = [i * 2 for i in x in l]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[[ 3 * i for i in inner ] for inner in outer]
```

Comment: whoul it be the same for subracting/adding

Comment: also how do i define outer

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> my_list = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]
>>> [map((3).__mul__, sublist) for sublist in my_list]
[[3, 6, 9], [9, 6, 3]]
```

You might consider using numpy arrays instead:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(my_list)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 2, 1]])
>>> 3*a
array([[3, 6, 9],
       [9, 6, 3]])
```